# jquery and select tag help

Tags: jquery

Firstly, I'm totally javascript inept so please explain throughly. OK, I have two issues going on here. I need to save data using JSON that posts back to my server side code. I first need to get the attribute values so they can be passed to the server. Where it pertains to input boxes, I'm good because that is straightforward but I can't seem to get the values for the selects.

The last problem I'm having is that I am using jwysiwyg and I cannot get the value of that either. I have 3 of the jqysiwyg on a single form. Each one has a different id. Can someone help me put this together?

---

Thanks to Rhaul, I was able to get the values of my selects but I'm still having a problem with getting the values of my editors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the value of a select box and your editor you can use [**`.val()`**](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

```
$("#yourselectboxid").val();
```

and

```
$("#youreditorid").val();
```

Comment: Hi rahul, let me try that. I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: Yes Rahul, that works for the selects. I'm not sure what I was doing wrong before but it wasn't working. Would you know how to get the values for my editors? I'm not able to get the editor values

Comment: Rahul, like this? `var ingredients = $("textarea#ingredients").val();`

Comment: If your editor id is `ingredients` then you can use `$("#ingredients").val()`, removing the `textarea` tag selector.

Comment: Hmm.. I've tried that, Rahul but all I get back is 'undefined'.

Comment: @Jim, this should work. Check your selector. Check whether `$("#ingredients").length` is 1 or not.

Comment: OK, this is what I get back. `ingredients=0`

Comment: Could you please inspect using Firebug what is the id of the editor?

Comment: Rahul, I found the problem. I had changed the selector name from ingredients to ta-ingredients and forgot. It returns the value now. Thank you so much. If I start a new thread, would you help me keep state on the select tags?

Comment: @Jim, happy to hear that this worked. Yes sure, post a new thread.